# How to make a filter possible with pagination

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

TYPO3 9
how can i set a filter for the widget.paginate?
Example:

```
<f:form name="filter" controller="myController" pluginName="Plugin" action="list" method="POST">
    <f:if condition="{types}">
        <f:for each="{types}" as="type">
            <f:form.checkbox name="filter[types][]" value="{type.uid}" />
        </f:for>
    </f:if>
    ...

<f:widget.paginate objects="{myObject}" as="Objects" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 20, insertAbove: 1, insertBelow: 1, maximumNumberOfLinks: 10, addQueryString: 1, addQueryStringMethod: 'POST'}">...
```

But this only works for the first page - the second page looses the parameters.

Next question: how can i set a nextPageLink (ajax) for the pagination? f:widget.link not working: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89522
Thank you :)

Answer (score -3):

Finally, I have found 2 solutions:

#### TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_yourext_plugin.features.requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 0
```

and

#### Controller: (Easy access via the methods parameter or via $ this->request)

```
public function listAction (int $ argument = 0) {...
```

## OR

#### ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cacheHash']['excludedParameters'][] = 'tx_yourext_plugin[argument]';
```

and

#### Controller:

```
public function listAction() {
    $argument = $this->request->getArgument('argument');
```

---

---

---

FLUID/HTML:

Solution 1:
Own normal HTML form (without FLUID / ViewHelper):

```
<form action = '<f:uri.action action = "cunning" controller = "job"/>' method = "GET">
<select name = "tx_yourext_plugin [argument]">...
```

Solution 2:
Own ViewHelper with the following contents
- then he can be used as the originals (he prevents only the production from automatically generated __ referrer hidden-fields as well as hidden-fields for trustedproperties):

```
class FormViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\FormViewHelper {
    protected function renderHiddenReferrerFields () {
        return ";
    }

    protected function renderTrustedPropertiesField () {
        return ";
    }
}
```

Many thanks to https://www.ophidia.net/fluid-fform-referrer-deaktivieren/

---

---

---

For both solutions:
FLUID paginate:
(Note: as of TYPO3 10 is addQueryStringMethod:'POST' depricated)

```
<f:widget.paginate... configuration = "{... addQueryString: 'true', addQueryStringMethod: 'GET'}">
```

---

---

---

BUT i have one problem left - i don't get pretty urls for the filter form.
So if i send the form the url is not nice - but if i use after that the pagination then the url is nice and clean.

Someone an idea?

```
MyPlugin:
type: Extbase
extension: MyExtKeyNameSpace
plugin: PluginName
defaultController: 'Controller::list'
routes:
  # - { routePath: '/{page-label}-{page}', _controller: 'Controller::list', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
  # - { routePath: '/{type-label}-{type}', _controller: 'Controller::list', _arguments: {'type': 'pluginTypes'} }
  # - { routePath: '/{area-label}-{area}', _controller: 'Controller::list', _arguments: {'area': 'pluginAreas'} }
  # - { routePath: '/type-{type}/area-{area}', _controller: 'Controller::list', _arguments: {'type': 'pluginTypes', 'area': 'pluginAreas'} }
  - { routePath: '/{page-label}{page}/{type-label}{type}/{area-label}{area}', _controller: 'Controller::list', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage', 'type': 'pluginTypes', 'area': 'pluginAreas'} }
  - { routePath: '/{company_slug}/{plugin_slug}', _controller: 'Controller::show', _arguments: {'company_slug': 'company', 'plugin_slug': 'plugin'} }
defaults:
  page: ''
  type: ''
  area: ''
requirements:
  page: '\d+'
  type: '\d+'
  area: '\d+'
aspects:
  page: { type: StaticRangeMapper, start: '1', end: '100' }
  page-label: { type: LocaleModifier, default: 'page-', localeMap: [{ locale: 'en_.*', value: 'page-' }, { locale: 'de_.*', value: 'seite-' }] }
  company_slug: { type: 'PersistedAliasMapper', tableName: 'tt_address', routeFieldName: 'slug' }
  plugin_slug: { type: 'PersistedAliasMapper', tableName: 'tx_myextkey_domain_model_plugin', routeFieldName: 'slug' }
  type-label: { type: LocaleModifier, default: 'type-', localeMap: [] }
  area-label: { type: LocaleModifier, default: 'area-', localeMap: [] }
```